# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"01/11/2012 08:00:00"

Tags: java, parsing, exception, date

I am trying to convert `Date` and `time` to calendar, while converting i am facing

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/11/2012 08:00:00"`

Here is my sample code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));  

cal.setTime(formatter.parse(Form.getRequestPortDate()+" "+.getRequestTimeDD()+":00"));
```

Note : Value of `Form.getRequestPortDate()+" "+Form.getRequestTimeDD()+":00")` is `01/11/2012 08:00:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));`

This means that you will be able to only parse the dates in the format `dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss`.

If you are getting dates in the format "01/11/2012 08:00:00" then you should use this string inside your `SimpleDateFormatter` :

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change date pattern to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

Answer (score 1):

your date is "`01/11/2012 08:00:00`" while the string you are trying to parse should be of format

```
"dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss
```

change  `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));`

to

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy H:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

Answer (score 1):

your **format** is **wrong**.

for this **date**: 01/11/2012 08:00:00
**format** should be :   `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

if you want to use your existing format, the **date** should be

```
   01/SEP/2012 8:00:00 (dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss)
```